# is sentence start with subject modifier considered valid?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence

A sentence popped up in my mind, goes:

“No longer a pain is that time in the cell, as he walk out from the jail."

And I am pretty sure I've seen something similar to this sentence, but I cannot tell grammatically whether this is a valid one or now. Can anyone points out if the sentence is problematic, or explain me the structure if it is good.

Comment: The example sentence in the question is ungrammatical—but not because of the reason suggested. A better example sentence would be something like this: *No longer painful, my daily exercises actually began to be enjoyable.* So, the short answer is that such a general construction can be grammatical; however, the example sentence used is not.

Comment: It seems like the main clause should be _he walks out from the jail_ and the other part could be a verbless clause in supplement function: _That time in the cell no longer a pain, he walks out from the jail_